# Chain together commands with SSH on ProCurve

Tags: shell, ssh, interactive

I need to back up the configuration of a HP ProCurve and I need to do it through SSH.

The ProCurve shell is interactive and I can't put something like:

```
$ ssh user@ip 'command1; command2'
```

...because the shell gives me an error — likely because the machine doesn’t actually have a Unix–like shell. I need to connect, input the password, and execute two commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Procurve/Cisco devices you can not simply run `ssh hostname command`. You need to use some tool that can work with interactive ssh sessions, i.e. expect, pexpect or something like this. Another solution is to use `socat`:

```
(sleep 5; echo ${PASSWORD}; sleep 2; echo ; echo command1; sleep 2) \
| socat - EXEC:"ssh ${SWITCH}",setsid,pty,ctty
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your question. Are you trying to run multiple commands?
Have you tried `sh -c` ?

```
ssh user@ip sh -c "command1; command2"
```

From `man sh`:

```
       -c               Read commands from the command_string operand instead of from the standard input.  Special parameter 0 will be set from the command_name operand
                        and the positional parameters ($1, $2, etc.)  set from the remaining argument operands.
```